# CDF of Pareto Distribution

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

I want to compute the CDF of a Pareto distribution

In particular, I have a Pareto distribution with p.d.f.

$$f(x) = \lambda x^{-(\lambda + 1)},$$

and I want to find the CDF of $f$. When I perform straightforward integration, I get

$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{w} \lambda w^{-\lambda + 1} \mathop{dw} = (-w^{-\lambda})\Big|_{-\infty}^{x} = -x^{-\lambda}$$

Is this right? Wolfram Alpha says my integration is correct, but it differs from the CDF provided on the Pareto Distribution's Wikipedia page. The wiki page suggests it should be $1 - x^{-\lambda}$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In general if $X$ has Pareto distribution with scale parameter $x_m>0$ and shape parameter $\lambda>0$ then its density is
$$
f_X(x) = \lambda x_m^\lambda x^{-(\lambda+1)}\cdot\mathsf 1_{(x_m,\infty)}(x).
$$
For any $x>x_m$, it follows by definition the density of an absolutely continuous random variable that the distribution function is given by
\begin{align}
F_X(x) :&= \mathbb P(X\leqslant x) \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^y f_X(y)\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \int_{x_m}^x \lambda x_m^\lambda y^{-(\lambda+1)}\ \mathsf dy\\
&= x_m^\lambda (x_m^{-\lambda}-x^{-\lambda})\\
&= 1 - \left(\frac{x_m}{x}\right)^\lambda.
\end{align}
In the case where $x_m=1$, this reduces to $$F_X(x) = \left(1-x^{-\lambda}\right)\cdot\mathsf 1_{(1,\infty)}(x).$$

Answer (score 0):

For pdf you have
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0, & x\leqslant 1\\
\lambda x^{-(\lambda + 1)}, & x> 1
\end{cases}$$
so
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{x} f(t)\,dt = \int\limits_{1}^{x} \lambda t^{-(\lambda + 1)}\,dt = 1 - x^{-\lambda}
$$
and we obtain
$$F(x)=\begin{cases}
0, & x\leqslant1\\
1-x^{-\lambda }, & x>1
\end{cases}$$